# Circular mean of equal mixture of two distributions?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

#### Problem

Suppose I have two "probability" vectors $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}$ each of whose elements corresponds to the weight of an evenly discretized circular space "support" $\Theta = [1 \cdot (2\pi/n), 2 \cdot (2\pi/n), \cdots, n \cdot (2\pi/n) ]^T$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{x} &= [x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n]^T \\
\mathbf{y} &= [y_1, y_2, \cdots, y_n]^T \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Note that the sums of their elements, $\sum x_i \equiv \sum y_i = 1$. We can calculate the "circular mean" $\bar{\mathbf{X}}$ and "circular precision" $\mathrm{prec}({\mathbf{X}})$ as follows:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\bar{\mathbf{X}} &= \mathrm{atan2} \left( \mathbf{x}^T \sin \Theta, \mathbf{x}^T \cos \Theta \right) \\ 
\mathrm{prec}({\mathbf{X}}) &= \sqrt{ \left( \mathbf{x}^T \sin \Theta \right)^2 + \left( \mathbf{x}^T \cos \Theta \right)^2 }
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\sin \Theta := [\sin \left(1 \cdot (2\pi/n)\right), \sin \left( 2 \cdot (2\pi/n) \right), \cdots, \sin \left( n \cdot (2\pi/n)\right) ]^T$, and cosine alike.

Now let $\mathbf{z} = (\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{y})/2$, the equal **mixture distribution** of $\mathbf{x}$, $\mathbf{y}$. Now I would like to clarify the following question:

> Question: Can we simplify circular mean $\bar{\mathbf{Z}}$, using $\bar{\mathbf{X}}$, $\bar{\mathbf{Y}}$, $\mathrm{prec}({\mathbf{X}})$, $\mathrm{prec}({\mathbf{Y}})$?

---

#### Expectation

$\bar{\mathbf{Z}}$ may look somewhat like $\bar{\mathbf{X}} \cdot \mathrm{prec}(\mathbf{X}) + \bar{\mathbf{Y}} \cdot \mathrm{prec}(\mathbf{Y})$.

---

#### Try

Thanks to the invariance of $\mathrm{atan2}$ to constant multiplication, *i.e.*, $\mathrm{atan2}(cx,cy) = \mathrm{atan2}(x,y)$ for $\forall c>0$, we have

$$
\begin{aligned}
\bar{\mathbf{Z}} &= \mathrm{atan2} \left( \mathbf{z}^T \sin \Theta, \mathbf{z}^T \cos \Theta \right) \\
&= \mathrm{atan2} \left( (\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y})^T \sin \Theta, (\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y})^T \cos \Theta \right) \\
&= \mathrm{tan}^{-1} \left( \frac{\mathbf{x}^T \sin \Theta + \mathbf{y}^T \sin \Theta}{\mathbf{x}^T \cos \Theta + \mathbf{y}^T \cos \Theta} \right)
\end{aligned}
$$

where $\mathbf{z}^T\cos\Theta >0$ assumed for the third equality for the sake of simplicity.

Letting $\mathbf{S}(\Theta) = \sin \Theta \sin \Theta^T$, $\mathbf{C}(\Theta) = \cos \Theta \cos \Theta^T$, $\mathbf{J}(\Theta) = \sin \Theta \cos \Theta^T$, we have

$$
\mathrm{prec} (\mathbf{X}) = \sqrt{ \mathbf{x}^T \left[\mathbf{S}(\Theta) + \mathbf{C} (\Theta) \right] \mathbf{x} }
$$

Moreover, using $\mathrm{tan}^{-1} (a/b) + \mathrm{tan}^{-1} (x/y) = \mathrm{tan}^{-1} \left( \frac{bx + ay}{by - ax} \right) $,

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{tan}^{-1} \left( \frac{\mathbf{x}^T \sin \Theta}{\mathbf{x}^T \cos \Theta} \right) + \mathrm{tan}^{-1} \left( \frac{ \mathbf{y}^T \sin \Theta}{\mathbf{y}^T \cos \Theta} \right) &= \mathrm{tan}^{-1} \left( \frac{\mathbf{x}^T \left[ \mathbf{J} (\Theta) - \mathbf{J} (\Theta)^T \right] \mathbf{y} }{\mathbf{x}^T \left[ \mathbf{C} (\Theta) - \mathbf{S} (\Theta) \right] \mathbf{y}} \right)
\end{aligned}
$$

From here, I did believe it was simple algebra, but I cannot proceed. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: May I ask where this came up from?

Comment: @Abbraxas I am working on the mixture of two wind direction distributions. I observed that the more "precise" distribution (with higher precision) generates an "attractive bias" of the overall circular mean direction. I'm trying to simplify the relation here.

Comment: Isn't $S(\Theta)+C(\Theta)=n$? Also, $J(\Theta)\in\mathbb R$, so the last part of the equation would be zero in the denominator.

Comment: @PeterKeller Please excuse my poor notations. I intended $\mathbf{S}(\Theta), \mathbf{C}(\Theta), \mathbf{J}(\Theta)$ to be matrices.

Comment: @Moreblue I see, i misread the notation then. $J(\Theta)-J(\Theta)^\top$ would then be zero on the diagonal and with trigonometric addition Theorem you would get something like a sine-Matrix. Something similar is true for the lower part; it should be some sort of cosine. But i don't see that this helps in any way.